# Review of php script to clean up orphaned images / pdfs on joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, images

I have written the following php script and would like some critique of the script and suggested improvements.
My motivation was to reduce server backup times and save energy by not backing up redundant / unused / orphaned files.
If enough website owners removed redundant files from backup we could have a significant impact on our ecological footprint.
If anyone wants to take it on and convert it to a component or plugin then please go ahead.
To test it please upload the file to your joomla directory and change the script to meet your requirements.
Don't run this on  a live site - or make a backup!!
https://github.com/ontargetWeb/cleanupjoomlafiles/blob/main/cleanfiles.php